# How to convert neomodel object into json? (is not JSON serializable)

Tags: python, json, falcon, neomodel

I use Falcon framework and neomodel in order to communicate with neo4j database.

I have some nodes in DB and I try to return information about them via API (get methon) as a JSON object.

In order to retrive information I use the code `people = Person.nodes`
I iterate throu people:

```
for p in people:
    print(p)
```

and I get:

```
{'name': 'John', 'id': 0, 'uid': '584d9b0517584b8194f222052bf177ff'}
{'name': 'Paul', 'id': 1, 'uid': 'f5763c01704e449885f846e87e1fcb6d'}
```

When I do `json.dumps()` on single entity I get an error:

```
TypeError: <Person: {'name': 'John', 'id': 0, 'uid': '584d9b0517584b8194f222052bf177ff'}> is not JSON serializable
```

How can I convert neomodel object into json object?

Comment: Valid json needs double quotes so try to replace the single quotes if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Using `json.dumps(p.__properties__)` does the trick. Using `p.__dict__` tries to encode the neomodel property classes, which will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like every `p` in your `people` is an object.
Try something like `json.dumps(p.__dict__)`. If it's a common neomodel node object then this should work.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an old question but this is how I work with this..

Creating a function on the class so I can control what data to return. With `__properies__` instead of the `.to_json` funtion you will get all properties.

```
class Player(StructuredNode):
  mid = IntegerProperty(unique_index=True)
  f_name = StringProperty()
  l_name = StringProperty()
  email = StringProperty()
  team = RelationshipFrom('Team', 'PLAYER', model=PlayerRel)

  def to_json(self):
    return {
        "id": self.mid,
        "firstName": self.f_name,
        "lastName": self.l_name,
        "email": self.email,
        "fullName": self.f_name + ' ' + self.l_name
    }
```

Then I have a node with has several Players connected and I just do this to return an array of players that can be serialized:

```
...
team = Team.nodes.get(team_id=id)
return ([player.to_json() for player in team.players])
```